# View Index numbers on PageView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on a project which uses PageView builder. I have total 30 number of item count. and in between every page I want to show ads. the problem is when ever I display it will start with Ads page and then go to page 1 then again to Ads page again this time it skip page 2 and directly jumps to page 3. How can I display them in ascending order without missing any number in between.

```
body: PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageController,
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final workoutindex = immunityBoosterworkoutlist[index];
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('Ads Page')),
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('page $index')),
              );
            }
}
```

pls refer this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSbLx.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You're currently getting pages like this Ad -> 1 Ad -> 3 -> Ad -> 5 -> Ad -> 7

Checkout this bunch of code. You'll get pages like this Ad -> 1 Ad -> 2 -> Ad -> 3 -> Ad -> 4 and so on. Hope that's what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int number = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController _pageController = PageController();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageView.builder(
        controller: _pageController,
        itemCount: 30,
        onPageChanged: (num) {

          // ============= main Login ==============

          setState(() {
            if (num % 2 != 0) {
              number += 1;
            }
          });


        },
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index % 2 == 0) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(child: Text('Ads Page')),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Center(child: Text('page ${index - number}')),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```